# How to extract specific value of a large batch of strings?

Tags: notepad

I have this information from notepad

```
          /----- Condition -----/   /-- Min. Height --/   /--- Righting ---/    /--- Heeling ---/    Area        Net
            Draft   Roll   Trim      W Tight  NW Tight        Arm      Area        Arm      Area     Ratio       Arm

            25.73   0.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       0.00       0.00       0.07       0.00      0.00    -0.072
            25.72   1.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       0.61       0.30       0.07       0.07      4.18     0.534
            25.70   2.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       1.22       1.21       0.08       0.15      8.24     1.139
            25.67   3.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       1.82       2.73       0.08       0.22     12.19     1.746
            25.64   4.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       2.44       4.87       0.08       0.30     15.99     2.355
            25.60   5.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       3.05       7.61       0.09       0.39     19.63     2.965
            25.55   6.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       3.67      10.97       0.09       0.47     23.09     3.578
            25.49   7.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       4.29      14.95       0.09       0.57     26.36     4.196
            25.44   8.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       4.92      19.55       0.10       0.66     29.47     4.821
            25.37   9.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       5.56      24.79       0.10       0.76     32.41     5.451
            25.30  10.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       6.20      30.66       0.11       0.87     35.18     6.086
            25.21  11.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       6.86      37.19       0.12       0.98     37.81     6.741
            25.01  12.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       7.66      44.45       0.12       1.10     40.32     7.539
            24.70  13.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       8.58      52.57       0.13       1.23     42.78     8.452
            24.35  14.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00       9.57      61.65       0.14       1.36     45.19     9.429
            23.96  15.00   0.00    9999.00    9999.00      10.62      71.74       0.15       1.51     47.58    10.472
```

I wish to extract the values for righting arm values like:

```
0.00
0.61
1.22
1.82
2.44
```

You know whats the quickest way to extract this values?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) or import it into a spreadsheet such as Excel or [Google Sheets](https://www.google.co.uk/sheets/about/).

Excel or Sheets will allow you to extract the column of data you want without hassle.

Lacking either of those Notepad++ can select and copy "columns" of data.

In Notepad++ you can hold the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while clicking and dragging (as you would normally to select a block of text) and will instead select the ***column*** of text from your start point to your end point.